# Can AWS EC2 describe-volumes show ownerarn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

I am using the aws ec2 describe-volumes with the out showing this:

```
{
    "Volumes": [
```

Is there anyway to include the `ownerarn` in this?

Comment: What is ownerarn? AWS cloud9?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CLI [describe-volumes documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html) shows the output that will be returned.

I'm not sure what you mean by `ownerarn`, but Amazon EBS volumes belong to an **AWS Account** that is identified by a 12-digit number. The Account ID is *not* returned as part of the `describe-volumes` call, but you can obtain it by calling `aws iam get-user` and extracting the Account ID from the returned Arn for the user.

Within AWS, resources are linked to AWS Accounts. They are *not* linked to IAM Users.